# Python hex IP as string to DDN IP string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysnmp

I have the following IP in hex: `0xac141315`

I would like to convert it to its DDN equivalent.
I used to use `'.'.join([str(x) for x in 0xac141315.asNumbers()])` when `0xac141315` had the following type: `<class 'CiscoNetworkAddress'>`

Or is there a way to convert the string back to `CiscoNetworkAddress`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `CISCO-TC` MIB, `CiscoNetworkAddress` is actually an octet string. There are many ways to turn octet string into a DDN. For example, with `ipaddress` module from Python 3 stdlib:

```
>>> from pysnmp.hlapi import OctetString
>>> ip = OctetString(hexValue='ac141315')  # this is what you have
>>>
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip.asOctets())
IPv4Address('172.20.19.21')
```

Or you can turn it into SNMP SMI IP address:

```
>>> from pysnmp.hlapi import IpAddress
>>> IpAddress(ip.asOctets()).prettyPrint()
'172.20.19.21'
```

Also, you could get a sequence of integer octets right from your existing object:

```
>>> ip.asNumbers()
(172, 20, 19, 21)
```

Keep in mind, that `CiscoNetworkAddress` is designed to hold many different address types, not just IPv4. So you should probably apply the IPv4 conversion only when it's actually IPv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of how to convert to decimal ip:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import sys  
# Must be (0xXXXXXXXX)  
if len(sys.argv)< 2:  
 print("Usage: %s (HEX FORMAT, for example 0xAC141315)" % sys.argv[0])  
sys.exit(0)  
user_option = sys.argv[1]  
hex_data=user_option[2:] 

#Check if length = 8  
if len(hex_data)< 8:  
hex_data = ''.join(('0',hex_data))  

def hex_to_ip_decimal(hex_data):  
 ipaddr = "%i.%i.%i.%i" % (int(hex_data[0:2],16),int(hex_data[2:4],16),int(hex_data[4:6],16),int(hex_data[6:8],16))  
return ipaddr  
result=hex_to_ip_decimal(hex_data)  
print result
```